# Como no commandButton do xhtml identificar que um erro foi gerado no Dao e manter a navegação na mesma pagina?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces-5.2

Na Pagina xhtml em um commandButton chamo a acao confirma() para confirmar a gravação de um objeto. O retorno desse metodo é uma string direcionando para uma nova pagina.

```
<p:commandButton id="botaoSalvar" value="Confirma" update="msgs" action="#{usuario_MB.confirma()}" ajax="false" process="@form"/>
```

Método confirma

```
public String confirma(){

        Grupo grupo = grupoDao.consulta("ROLE_USER");
        List<Grupo> grupos = new ArrayList<>();
        grupos.add(grupo); 
        usuario.setGrupos(grupos);
        usuarioDao.inclusao(usuario);
        return "/Login.xhtml";
    }
```

No método inclusao da da classe UsuarioDao trato as exceçoes.

```
public void inclusao(Usuario usuario) {


        System.out.println("\n -------- Entrou no Usuario.consulta - antes do EM");
        try {
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            entityManager.persist(usuario);
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            FacesUtil.addInfoMessage("Usuario cadastrado com sucesso!");
        } catch (EntityExistsException e){
            System.out.println("\n -------- Erro ao incluir usuario - ChaveDublicada");
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
            FacesUtil.addErrorMessage("Usuario já cadastrado!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("\n -------- Erro ao incluir usuario");
            FacesUtil.addErrorMessage("Algo não funcionou! Tente mais tarde.");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }

    }
```

A duvida é a seguinte:

> Como no commandButton do xhtml identifico que um erro foi gerado e
>   mantenho a navegação na mesma pagina?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você retornar "" no seu managedBean:

```
public String confirma(){
    Grupo grupo = grupoDao.consulta("ROLE_USER");
    List<Grupo> grupos = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        grupos.add(grupo); 
        usuario.setGrupos(grupos);
        usuarioDao.inclusao(usuario);
        return "/Login.xhtml";
    }catch(Exception e){//...}
    return ""; //<- isso faz com que não haja troca de página
}
```

Obs: relance a exception no seu método `inclusao()`